# fglrx kernel 3.18.22

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, fglrx, amd-graphics, dkms

I'm trying to compile kernel 3.18.22 and while the kernel successfully compiles I can't get Catalyst 15.9 to work. According to AMD's website it should work with anything up to kernel 3.19. The driver works fine with default debian kernel(3.16). I even tried 3.19 with no luck. I get the following when I install the kernel:

```
DKMS make.log for fglrx-15.201.1151 for kernel 3.18.22 (x86_64)
Sun Oct 4 19:59:02 PDT 2015
AMD kernel module generator version 2.1
doing Makefile based build for kernel 2.6.x and higher
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'clean'. Stop.
make[2]: *** No targets. Stop.
build failed with return value 2
```

I got fglrx from AMD's website and the kernel from kernel.org. I installed fglrx using the installer. I followed [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernels/Compilation/Traditional) tutorial for compiling. I used `make localmodconfig` to copy my current config using the defaults for any new entries. The config is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzW0t4K6XI4gNk1HN0VjaGUxTXc). The DKMS error was located in the log after doing `make install` for the kernel.

Comment: What distribution? And why aren't you using a prebuilt binary kernel? And what fglrx source are you using for building?

Comment: I'm on Debian 8 Jessie, systemd, UEFI and because I just want to try compiling a kernel. I've successfully done it on my laptop with 4.2.3 but my laptop doesn't have any proprietary drivers. As far as fglrx I'm using the one that ships with catalyst 15.9. I don't think there are others given that it's proprietary.

Comment: Ok. With Debian you should use the Debian sources for fglrx. See https://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary#AMD_Catalyst_14.9 . I'm on Jessie too. And use a stock kernel, at least to start with. Can you spell out your steps a bit more, please? `module-assistant` (`m-a`) isn't so popular these days, but is a valid alternative to `dkms`.

Comment: By steps do you mean how I compiled it? I'll edit my post and I'll look into module-assist. Never actually heard of it. I'll also look at using the Debian sources. The driver actually works fine on the default Debian 3.16 kernel though. I edited my post since I neglected to mention that originally.

Comment: By steps I mean whatever steps you took to get to the error message you show above. Including where you got your kernel and fglrx driver from, and how you compiled them. Using stock Debian kernels and Debian kernel module sources is usually the most painless way to get this kind of thing working. Also, the Debian kernel module sources build a deb for the module, which is a good thing.

Comment: Kernel was form kernel.org, driver was from AMD's site and was installed using the installer. The error showed up in the log file after doing `make install`

Comment: Put all that info in the question, not in comments. And in general, note that @username is needed if you want to notify someone, though in this case, I'm notified anyway. Anyway, I suggest that (if you want to get your machine working) use the stock Debian kernel and the Debian module sources as I described above. If you want to experiment, that's fine, but do it after you have got your machine working.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Yea I know about the @ thing. I just didn't do it. I made this post at like 2:00AM last night or something. Also I did edit my post but I posted in the comments as well so you didn't have to go back and read it. I've messed up enough on here to know the practices haha. Anyway thanks for the suggestion regarding using Debian sources.